multiclass SVM on big Dataset
I have a code as below which is related to using multiclass svm on a large dataset with almost 500,000 rows and 41 features. But it takes a very long time to run and doesn't finish after hours.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\KDDCup99.csv")
shifted_data = data.shift(+2)
shuffle_data = shifted_data.sample(frac=1)
random_sample = shuffle_data.head(494021)
X = random_sample.iloc[:, :41]
X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['protocol_type', 'service', 'flag'])
Y = random_sample.iloc[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, Y, test_size=0.25, shuffle=False)
linear = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_train, Y_train)
rbf = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.5, C=0.1).fit(X_train, Y_train)
poly = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=1).fit(X_train, Y_train)
line_pred = linear.predict(X_test)
rbf_pred = rbf.predict(X_test)
poly_pred = poly.predict(X_test)
line_accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, line_pred)
rbf_accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, rbf_pred)
poly_accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, poly_pred)
line_recall = recall_score(Y_test, line_pred, average="macro", zero_division=1)
rbf_recall = recall_score(Y_test, rbf_pred, average="macro", zero_division=1)
poly_recall = recall_score(Y_test, poly_pred, average="macro", zero_division=1)
print('Accuracy (Linear Kernel): %.2f' % (line_accuracy * 100))
print('Recall for Linear Kernel:')
print(line_recall)
print('Accuracy (RBF Kernel): %.2f' % (rbf_accuracy * 100))
print('Recall for RBF Kernel:')
print(rbf_recall)
print('Accuracy (Polynomial Kernel): %.2f' % (poly_accuracy * 100))
print('Recall for Polynomial Kernel:')
print(poly_recall)
np.savetxt('X_train.txt', X_train, fmt='%f', delimiter='\n')
np.savetxt('X_test.txt', X_test, fmt='%f', delimiter='\n')
np.savetxt('Y_train.txt', Y_train, fmt='%s')
np.savetxt('Y_test.txt', Y_test, fmt='%s')
np.savetxt('line_pred.txt', line_pred, fmt='%s')
np.savetxt('poly_pred.txt', poly_pred, fmt='%s')
np.savetxt('rbf_pred.txt', rbf_pred, fmt='%s')

Since I have a good system, it doesn't cause any problem and I even tried Google Colab to make sure, but it didn't work. I tried to use svmlight but it was not very interesting and I even changed the code so that it can use all CPU cores but it was still unsuccessful. plus i got same result with Linear SVC TOO. Does anyone know a better way? Or can it optimize the code?
